# Processing input="file" array

Tags: php, html

I have a html form like so:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]" required>
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]">
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]">
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]">
    <input type="file" name="pictures[]">
</form>
```

such that, a user can upload up to 5 pictures. I know that I can do it with `<input type="file" name="pictures[]" multiple>`, but the idea is that, I want the users to be able to select files from different folders of their device(s), hence the reason why I wrote in the format above.

Now, the challenge I am having now is that, not all the inputs are required, and when the form is submitted, and I do the normal input checks `$_FILES['pictures']['name]`, it loops through all the file array, which is normal since they have the same name.

Now my headache..

- How do I validate only the inputs that a file is entered while maintaining the one required field?

For now, if I do a check `$_FILES['pictures']['name']` when less than 5 files are added in the input boxes, it returns an error because of the input field(s) that were not entered.

**EDIT**

First I check if at least one file was entered, then I check if any of the files do not return any error. See my code below:

```
if ( count($_FILES['pictures']['name']) < 1 ) {
    echo "Please enter at least one image";
}
elseif ( $_FILES['pictures']['error'] != 0 ) {
    echo "Sorry, one or more of your uploaded images is invalid";
}
```

Now the form will always return an error if not all the 5 inputs fields are entered.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Maybe I wasn't able to explain clearly what I wanted to achieve.. but here's the gist.

Apart from the fact that one of the inputs is required, when the form is submitted without all the fields entered, and I do something like so *(skipping the required check)*:

```
$files = array();
$fileData = $_FILES['pictures'];
$files = array();
if ( is_array($fileData['name']) ) {

    for ( $i=0; $i < count($fileData['name']) ; ++$i ) {
        $files[] = array(
            'name' => $fileData['name'][$i],
            'tmp_name' => $fileData['tmp_name'][$i],
            'type' => $fileData['type'][$i],
            'error' => $fileData['error'][$i],
            'size' => $fileData['size'][$i],
        );        
    }
}
else {
    $files[] = $fileData;
}
```

So when I perform validations like:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ( $file['name'] == '' ) {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
```

, and the user did not enter all the images, it returns the error message.

A `print_r()` of the `$files` returns this:

```
Array
(
    [photos] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11356010_127900540886840_1152019271_n.jpg
                    [1] => 11370980_130679033939470_1067474802_n.jpg
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => 
                    [3] =>
                    [4] =>  
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp7\tmp\php1C9F.tmp
                    [1] => C:\xampp7\tmp\php1CaF.tmp
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 4
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 108492
                    [1] => 108492
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                )

        )

    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Is there a way I can make the empty fields to be ignore when doing my checks?

I know I can do this with javascript by checking for the empty fields and add the attribute of `disabled` on submit, but what if the user turned off javascript in his/her browser, what happens?

I've tried using `array_filter()` like so:

```
$filtered = array_filter($_FILES['pictures'], function($var){
    return !empty($var['pictures']['name']);
});
```

, but it returns an empty array. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: If something is inputed then `name` key is not empty. If something is inputed and uploaded successfully then `error` key is 0.

Comment: Yes, but if less than 5 files are uploaded and I do a check for files with empty `name`, it returns an error, because of the other input that was not entered.

Comment: I don't see the code which checks, I can't help you.

Comment: Can you please show some code demonstrating what you've tried but isn't working? I think that would help demonstrate the problem.

Comment: use jQuery to validate and then $( "form").submit();

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: what i understand is you want to let user upload at least one image but when they upload less than five image there is error , i am i right?

Comment: No. I want to let the user upload at least one image, Yes, and I know how to do that. My question is, _**how do I make the fields that were not entered by the user to be ignored during my checks**_?

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['pictures']['error']` will end up being an array of error codes, so you can loop over it and handle them explicitly. There is a [good example of this in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-385).

In your case, you may want to handle the first iteration of the loop as a special case, since you've defined the first one as being required. Something like this:

```
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($key == 0 && $error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // the required one didn't succeed, so we have a problem
    } else {
        // ...
```

Comment: How do I check for the other inputs based on how many that were actually entered?

Comment: That would be the `else` part of this solution. As you continue looping, you will see if there were other errors. If not, just proceed. Have you tried `var_dump($_FILES["pictures"]);` to see what that whole array looks like? That might help with the understanding of it.

Comment: Yes I have done that, and it returned `empty` for the `name` and `tmp_name`, `0` for the `size` and an error because no files were seen from the remaining items in the emtpy array.

Comment: I copied your code exactly, and after uploading one file via the "required" input, my `var_dump` looks like this: https://pastebin.com/fbPCatMz What are you doing differently to get empty and zero?

Comment: Exactly! When I do a `foreach` loop to check if any of the uploaded files returned an error `4`, it returns true, if all the input fields are not entered.

Comment: It's ok if the 2nd through 5th ones have error `4`, right? Can't you just account for that in your code & continue processing the one that _was_ uploaded?

Comment: Well, no. A user may upload more than one image, and it is very possible that one or more of their chosen image's `error` != `0`. So, how do I check in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

because it is an array use in_array() http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
<?php
$os = $_FILES["pictures"]["error"];
 if (in_array("0", $os)) {
echo "done";
}else{
echo "error";
}
 ?>
```